# Incomplete collection member when migrating to SCCM 2012 (from SCCM 2007)

Tags: migration, sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2007

I am new in learning about SCCM.
I want to ask why my collection member didn't migrated completely from SCCM 2007 to SCCM 2012? It happens on random member.
I am sure have specified the source hierarchy correctly and no permission issue. I run collection migration, where in the source hierarchy I dont have any subcollection (just standard collection), all collection migrated successfully but most of them has 0 member. The number of member in "all users" collection between SCCM 2007 and SCCM 2012 is also far different (SCCM 2012 has less member than 2007)
Please help me solve this. Thanks.

PS: I know in SCCM 2012 the collection for user and workstation are now separated but still combining the numbers of user+workstation in 2012 has less number than 2007.

PS #2 : the collection migration jobs is complete without any error or failed alert, and while migrating, the button "view objects that can't be migrated" is greyed out, means that no objects that can't be migrated

Answer (score 1):

When migrating collections, the clients still need to be upgraded to 2012 in order to be discoverd/visible.

You can overlap bounderies so the client-push will install the new client version.
But 2007 client not be visible before they are upgraded/discoverd.

So first verify if you target client(s) has the correct client version 5=2012 (control panel -> security -> configuration manager)

Remember to set correct bounderies if you have multiple secondary sites.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, apparently it was because my own fault. already updated my own answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Now that I noticed it, most of collections with 0 member are collections that using query in its membership rule. Somehow, I figured out that even though the query is correct but it returns nothing.

Apparently it was because of I haven't enabled AD discovery options in **administration > overview > hierarchy configuration > discovery methods**

Everything works after I enable those options, even though it still not displaying the exact same number... still working to figure this out but I think the main issue has been solved.

Thankyou